# Hodge decomposition in weight Sobolev space

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold with cylindrical ends, i.e., the ends of $(M, g)$ are modelled on $([0, \infty)_s\times Y, g=ds^2 +g_{Y}).$  I want to know whether the Hodge decomposition for $L^2_{\delta}$ forms is true or not.  It would be appreciated if anyone can provide me with references on the question. The details of my question are as follows:

Let $E \to M$ be a vector bundle. To do analysis on $(M,g)$, it is natural to consider the weight Sobolev space $W^{k,p}_{\delta}(E)$. More precisely, let $\delta: M \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function with support on the ends of $M$ and $\delta=constant$ when $s \ge R_0$. Then the weight Sobolev    $W^{k,p}_{\delta}$ is the completion of $C_c^{\infty}(M, E)$ with respect to norm 
$$|u|^p_{W^{k,p}_{\delta}}=\sum_{m=0}^k \int_M|e^{
\delta s} \nabla^mu|^p vol_g.  $$

Now I focus on $E=\Lambda^qTM^*$. Let $d$ be the exterior derivative and $d^{*}_{\delta}$ be the adjoint with respect to the inner product $L^2_{\delta}$. Define a Laplacian operator by
$$D=d+d^*_{\delta}.$$

My question: Is the Hodge decomposition true for Sobolev space $L^2_{\delta}(M, \Lambda^qTM^*)$(at least for very small $\delta$), i.e.,
$$L^2_{\delta}(\Lambda^qTM^*)=Im\{d: W^{1,2}_{\delta}(\Lambda^{q-1}TM^*) \to L^{2}_{\delta}(\Lambda^{q-1}TM^*)  \} \oplus Ker D \oplus Ker\{d_{\delta}^*:  W^{1,2}_{\delta}(\Lambda^{q+1}TM^*) \to L^{2}_{\delta}(\Lambda^{q}TM^*)   \}.$$